# AXI Protocol, difference between secure and non-secure transactions

Tags: vivado, zynq, axi4

Just wanted to ask, what is the difference between secure and non-secure transactions when it comes to AXI bus transactions?

What are the performance implications of either transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusted transactions are a part of ARM's TrustZone policy.  It requires an additional pin to indicate a secure connection.  It only allows communication with the secure section of the processor.  It is a **software** solution to restrict access to hardware in the case of root access on the OS.  It acts as a firewall in the event a hacker takes control of the OS.  **It does not guard against hardware hacking**.

As far a performance, the hardware bandwidth is unaffected, but the extra step in the secure processor does incur a performance penalty.